# Convert dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm tt to MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm tt in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to convert string as : `"25/12/2017 4:00 PM"` to `"12/25/2017 4:00 PM"`. My code :

```
var TDXRSC = "25/12/2017 4:00 PM";
DateTime.ParseExact(TDXRSC, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But it's not working.

Comment: What does "But it's not working." mean?

Comment: I think you simply need `""dd/MM/yyyy h:mm tt""`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is your date format expected is `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt` but the reference date only has a single digit hour `4`. You are probably better off not expect leading zeros for days, months or hours.

Try..

```
var TDXRSC = "25/12/2017 4:00 PM";
var input = DateTime.ParseExact(TDXRSC, "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This will also still parse 2 digit hours. So `var TDXRSC = "25/12/2017 12:00 PM";` will still parse correctly.

Comment: I got it. Thank you , @Nico.

Comment: @Ken99 good work. I suggest trying different scenarios of missing leading 0's or single digit values Months & Days could also cause a problem in the future

Answer (score 0):

```
var TDXRSC = "25/12/2017 4:00 PM";
var input = DateTime.ParseExact(TDXRSC, "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var output = input.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt");
```

When you call `ParseExact` you're telling the compiler what format the incoming date is. You can then use `ToString()` method to provide a format for a string representation of the parsed date.

Comment: Did you test this code? `FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

Comment: When i call ParseExact , i get a error : "string was not recognized as a valid datetime"

Comment: @Enigmativity code is fine, the input date format may be incorrect but the concept is sound

Comment: @CynePhoba12 - You've got it the other way around. The input date is correct (as it is what the OP gave us) and your code is incorrect.

Comment: @Enigmativity his question asked how to convert it to another format. I have provided a solution to convert which was not provided elsewhere. I am aware the format was incorrect but I have fixed it since you are so adamant that I am incorrect but did not provide a full solution yourself :)

Comment: @CynePhoba12 - The OP didn't actually ask a question. There isn't actually one there at all. But he did make it clear that his current code wasn't working and you pasted the same code. I'm not obliged to provide a solution of mine own in order to help others improve theirs. In fact all members of Stack Overflow are encouraged to help improve the quality of all questions and all answers.

Comment: @Enigmativity _I want to convert string as : "X" to "Y"_. I provided a solution to converting to "Y" because his code did not contain it. Sorry you feel that way x

Comment: @CynePhoba12 - I understand what you're saying, but your original solution did **not** convert "X" to "Y". It was as broken as the OP's code. The OP didn't ask a question. It was up to us to interpret what he wanted. The biggest clue was the "But it's not working." in reference to the code he posted.

Answer (score 0):

Hope that `.TryParseExtract` will be more safe to use for conversion, use like the following:

```
var dateString = "25/12/2017 4:00 PM";
DateTime inputDate; 
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out inputDate))
{
   var output = inputDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt");
   Console.WriteLine(output);
}
else
{
     Console.WriteLine("Conversion failed");
}
```

[Working Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ljz3Ud)

Answer (score 0):

```
var TDXRSC = "25/12/2017 4:00 PM";
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(TDXRSC);
string Format = date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt");
```